# Why PyCharm tkinter GUI is not working in macOS Monterey 12 update?

Tags: macos, tkinter, pycharm, macos-monterey

Today I updated the macOS to Monterey. And so far faced some problems for which I got few solutions, but for this problem there no Solution anywhere!!
When I run a tkinter program then GUI window is blank black.
This is a headache for me today.
Help!!

Comment: Which version of Python? Which version of TKinter? Which version of Tcl/Tk? What is the actual code that is not working? (preferably distilled down to a minimal example, not all the code in your project)

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what exactly is wrong? Is the window empty, and it's black instead of the usual cream? Or did you add widgets to the window? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help.

Comment: @joachim I am using python 3.8 and all was working smooth before the monterey update. Then suddenly everything changes.

Comment: Usually i was developing a pong game in Tkinter GUI, BEFORE the GUI was working fine, but now the GUI is plane black. The Sublime text was also giving an error. Installation of xcode using some command helped.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. Just updating to Python 3.10.0 from http://www.python.org solved this problem for me.

The 3.10.0 installer gives us a glimpse of this fix as you can see in this image taken from it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently have Macs updated to Python 3.10.+ on Monterey and GUIs continue to be black. Updating to Python 3.10+ is not always enough. Using Brew to install Python 3.10+ seems to be the answer for me and my students.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32696539)