# How do I change the background color in python tkinter?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Python noob here, ive started a tkinter tutorial and no matter what method I use to change the background color it stays black. Im using vs code on mac and I made sure everything is updated. Ive also tried it in pycharm and the same problem occurs. Im not getting any errors in the terminal. Here is what I have,

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Weather.py")
window.config(bg="blue")
window.mainloop()
```

Any ideas?

Update:
Tried it on another mac in the house and is seemed to work on that one. Not sure why it wont work on mine.

Comment: Have you tried running it directly from Terminal? It works fine for me on Windows.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the tip. Yes I just made sure that i have been running in the terminal. Still that black screen rather than a blue one. It displays my title at the top. I thought that maybe it had something to do with the fact that I had dark mode turned on, but with that turned off now it still shows the same thing. Weird...

Comment: What version of python do you have? Maybe try updating to the newest version? Looks like it might be similar to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71294521/tkinter-window-appears-black-upon-running-in-pycharm)

Comment: This works on my windows as well. Have you tried reinstalling `Python` or the `Tkinter` package?

Comment: @bob_has_a_question Maybe you can try doing it in IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link provided by @Rory did the trick... Along with several restarts of both the computer and vs code.