# tk.label and grid not showing text entry box

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, label

I am trying to print out a text entry box on a gui but when I do it nothing happens. All I get is a blank screen with the title showing. The text entry box does not appear. Doing this in python. Any Help would be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk

DEFAULT_ARGS = ('MMM', 'AAPL')

root = tk.Tk()

root.title(DEFAULT_ARGS)


firstLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Stock Ticker: ")
firstLabel.grid(row=5, column=1)

firstEntry = tk.Entry(root)
firstEntry.grid(row=1, column=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code shows a `Label` below and to the left of an `Entry` when I run it.  Is this what you expect?  Try  stretching the gui window in case the `entry` is hidden.  Did you mean an `Entry` widget as a `Text` widget is something different?

Comment: This code works for me. Are you certain _this code_ exhibits the problem you say? Also, are you on a Mac?

Comment: I am on a mac. The code works on my friend's computer but not on mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter window appears black upon running in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71294521/tkinter-window-appears-black-upon-running-in-pycharm)

Comment: @relent95. An OP solved problem. I had to deleted my answer.