# Tkinter Showing a Blank Screen Pycharm

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

I'm trying to learn Tkinter in PyCharm but whenever I run the code the box comes out like this:

[tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYvu0.png)

Here's how it looks when I expand the box

[tkinterExpanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7uuJ.png)

Here's my code

```
#import all modules in tkinter
from tkinter import *

#creates the base, or root, widget that all other widgets will be in
root = Tk()

#creates a label widget
myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello World!")

#shoves the label widget onto the screen
myLabel.pack()

#this is the main loop that will keep looping to update the screen
root.mainloop()
```

I was expecting a white box with the words "Hello World" but this did not happen. What I got is the empty box seen in the images.

I am running this on an M2 Mac Air

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem on my Mac.  Upgrading the version of Python to 3.12.0 fixed the issue.  See [Why PyCharm tkinter GUI is not working in macOS Monterey 12 update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69844250/why-pycharm-tkinter-gui-is-not-working-in-macos-monterey-12-update)